# How to enable one field based on another object field

Tags: relationships

For a Pending or Active Partner (using the Partner Status field on the Account), we need to look at all of their “Active” (checkbox on the Solution/Accrediation object) related Solution/accreditation records.
[image]
If any of those records have the field “Direct” checked “True”, 
[image]
then the checkbox on the Account field Is Direct, should be checked “True”.  This box would be checked to False if none of the Solutions records have Direct checked True.

How to achieve this, should we create any validation rule or workflow?
It would be grateful if anyone solve my issue and i would appreciate. kindly solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Validation Rule will not work, it just checks the data being entered. Workflow rule would work possibly using a cross-object field update, but don't think it would cover all scenarios adequately.

I would look towards using Process Builder with Flow combo. Process would fire on create/edit of Solution/Accreditation object then call a Flow. The flow would query all Solution Accreditation records for the Partner Account. This collection of records would then be looped in the flow to determine if at least one is Direct. If direct, then update the related account record.

This is not the exact solution but should help you with the flow part

http://www.salesforceweek.ly/2015/02/how-to-create-roll-up-summaries-using-flow.html